# Red hat Linux + TIME ZONE CONFIGURATION + details from clock file

Tags: linux, redhat, timezone, date, clock-synchronization

In order to configure the Time Zone on red hat Linux machine ( version 5 and 6 )
need to configure 
the file:

```
/etc/sysconfig/clock
```

And create a symbolic link between

```
/etc/localtime to /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/New_York
```

but `/etc/sysconfig/clock` also required to set the `ZONE` variable as the following example:

```
ZONE="America/New_York"
```

So what is the need to set the variable **`ZONE=America/New_York`** when it is very clear from the link **`/etc/localtime`** that is pointed to `/usr/share/zoneinfo/**America/New_York**` ?

So what is the need to set the **`ZONE`** parameter with "`America/New_York`" value ?

Comment: I'm voting to move this question to [unix.se] since it's more about how a particular Linux version works than about professional systems administration. In other words, the close vote currently on your question is not about actually closing but about moving.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So the "correct" way to set the clock (at least prior to RHEL 7) is to edit `/etc/sysconfig/clock` and then run `tzdata-update` which will then update `/etc/localtime`; you've just done that step manually.

Comment: this not working on my linux machine redhat 5 , for example I configure the clock file as ZONE=Japan , and run the tzdata-update but time was not change to Japan TIME ZONE , or I missed something ?

Comment: I think it should be `Asia/Tokyo`.

Comment: https://blog.nexcess.net/2014/01/15/changing-the-timezone-in-centos-from-the-cli/ also explains why it was set up the way it is. By not updating `/etc/sysconfig/clock` the next time the `tzdata` package is updated your timezone may revert back to whatever it was before you manually changed `/etc/localtime`.

Comment: I set the variable to ZONE="Asia/Tokyo"  , but still after tzdata-update I not get the Japan TZ ( from date )

Comment: Odd. I just tried both `Japan` and `Asia/Tokyo` as values on my RHEL 5 machine and it worked correctly for me in both cases. Do you have a complete `tzdata` package installed, i.e. everything under `/usr/share/zoneinfo`?

Comment: yes , I try to installed by yum the tzdata but on my machine the latest version installed , meenwhile /etc/localtime not created when I run the tzdata-update and under zoneingo I have all countries

Comment: yes now I success but tzdata-update not create the link to /etc/localtime - why?

Answer (score 8):

With the introduction of RHEL 7 the timezone is managed through systemd, which provides a custom utility to change the timezone: [`timedatectl`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/timedatectl.html)

To list all available time zones:

```
timedatectl list-timezones
```

To actually change the time zone, (as root or using `sudo`):

```
timedatectl set-timezone time_zone
```

[`timedatectl set-timezone`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/timedatectl.html#set-timezone%20%5BTIMEZONE%5D) will not only make the modified time zone take effect immediately, but will  also update the `/etc/localtime` symlink to make that change persistent across reboots.

Comment: The question explicitly says RHEL 5 and 6.

Comment: @MichaelHampton The question has been [edited to clarify the RHEL release](https://serverfault.com/posts/791637/revisions) only after I posted the answer above...

Comment: Oh, that figures.