# CentsOS 6 returning wrong time

Tags: centos6, timezone

Our current local time is 22:35 11 Jun 2020

I have set the CentOS time zone to Asia/Kuwait

```
[root@server etc]# ls -l /etc/localtime
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 6 Jun 11  2020 /etc/localtime -> Kuwait
```

But current date command is retuning a wrong datetime:-

```
[root@server Asia]# date
Thu Jun 11 19:38:11 UTC 2020
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a broken symlink, as tzdata should be at `/usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Kuwait`.

Follow the [EL6 and earlier procedure to edit time zone](https://serverfault.com/a/791648/241174).  Edit `/etc/sysconfig/clock` to `Asia/Kuwait`  and run `tzdata-update`

Comment: The file already set to Asia/Kuwait [root@server Asia]# cat /etc/sysconfig/clock
ZONE="Asia/Kuwait"
UTC=false
ARC=false
i run tzdata-update nothing changed

Comment: Then `unlink /etc/localtime`   symlink it to /usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Kuwait,  and confirm the link is not broken.